# Javascript compiler exception: missing ) after for-loop control

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am getting an error "Javascript compiler exception: missing ) after for-loop control (null.null.script; line 29)" which would be the instantiation of the loop. My syntax looks correct.
a little help please...

```
var ciArray = [];
var i;
var check;
for (i = 0; check = false; i < ciArray.length; i++) {
   
   if(ciValue == ciArray[i,0]){
     ciArray[i,1] += timer;
     check =True;
     }
   if(i == mciArray.length-1 && !check) {
     ciArray[i+1,0] = ciValue;
     ciArray[i+1,1] = timer;
     }
}
```

Comment: you only can have 2 semicolons in the control for a `for` lop. use a comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many arguments for your for loop - looks more like a while loop with a check clause right now.

Answer (score 0):

inside of condition the loop for you have (i = 0; check = false; <--- in this options it your error.